# Signature pad doesn't draw on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, signaturepad

I have a signature pad in a laravel project that work in desktop but when I test in mobile it doesn't work.

I search a lot about this problem, I tried from another ways...
I check meta tags, I check cdnjs link, I create a new view to put just this peace of code and don't work. I don't know what is the problem.

If I go to demo page(http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/) and try run this on mobile works!

So, I found an example and I tried to do this exactly in my laravel project and doesn't work. After that I put the same code in jsfiddle and works (https://jsfiddle.net/6brfy7gq/1/).

It works in desktop, I can draw, save image, all things but when I try mobile don't work. But as you can check the same code in jsfiddle works in mobile. I noticed that I can't scroll the page above `canvas` in jsfiddle mobile but in my laravel project it scrolls. Maybe this is the problem.
 I don't know what to try more!

So, what is the diferences between my code and this?
In js file I have the code inside `document ready` like this:

```
      $(document).ready(function ()
      {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
        var clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]");
        var savePNGButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save-png]");
        var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-canvas');



        // Adjust canvas coordinate space taking into account pixel ratio,
        // to make it look crisp on mobile devices.
        // This also causes canvas to be cleared.
        function resizeCanvas() {
            var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
            canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
            canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
            canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
        }
        // On mobile devices it might make more sense to listen to orientation change,
        // rather than window resize events.
        window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
        resizeCanvas();
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);


        function download(dataURL, filename) {
          var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataURL);
          var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          var a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style = "display: none";
          a.href = url;
          a.download = filename;

          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();

          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }

        // One could simply use Canvas#toBlob method instead, but it's just to show
        // that it can be done using result of SignaturePad#toDataURL.
        function dataURLToBlob(dataURL) {
          // Code taken from https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js
          var parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
          var contentType = parts[0].split(":")[1];
          var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
          var rawLength = raw.length;
          var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

          for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
            uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
          }

          return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
        }

        clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
          signaturePad.clear();
        });


        savePNGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

          var dataUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL();
          //document.getElementById('imagen_firma').src = dataUrl;
          var image = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
          $('input[name=signatureImage]').val(image);
          //download(dataURL, "signature.png");

        });


      });
```

And html was loaded to a blade view like this:

```
<div class="sub-title">
      <span>Signature</span>
    </div>
    <div class="data new" >

      <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
        <div class="signature-pad--body">
          <canvas id="signature-canvas" style="width:650px;height:420px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-pad--footer">
          <div class="description">Sign above</div>

          <div class="signature-pad--actions">
            <div>
              <i class="button clear icon-cancel" data-action="clear" style="font-size:2em;" title="Clear"></i>
              <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png" style="visibility:hidden">Save as PNG</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{ Form::hidden('signatureImage', old('signatureImage')) }}
```

I can try anything...

Thank you a lot

Comment: the problem was to have the code inside the document.ready! But I do not understand why Anyone can explain me?